# SQL Server Query In and Out

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is from DTR Device that i saved in Ms sql database

`ID    | Employee_ID | Date                | InOutMode
-------+-------------+---------------------+-----------
 70821 |    104      | 2019-10-11 19:00:00 |    0
 70850 |    104      | 2019-10-12 07:01:00 |    1`

if i'm going to separate the IN and OUT it suppose to be like this:

`ID    | Employee_ID | IN                  | OUT
-------+-------------+---------------------+-----------
 70821 |    104      | 2019-10-11 19:00:00 | 2019-10-12 07:01:00`

What happens is, i don't know if my queries were wrong. the TIME-OUT is not 2019-10-12 but 2019-10-11 same as the TIME-IN it looks like this:

`ID    | Employee_ID | IN                  | OUT
-------+-------------+---------------------+-----------
 70821 |    104      | 2019-10-11 19:00:00 | 2019-10-11 07:01:00`

Comment: _Gone wrong_ doesn't mean anything. Please explain what you are expecting

Comment: If you also paste in the data for the relevant period then we can quickly recreate the data and make it work. Just too hard if someone has to type the data in from your pictures.

Comment: s you can see the IN AND OUT was incorrect.. it should be the IN = 2019-10-11 19:00:00 and the OUT should be 2019-10-12 07:01:00 because the employee IN by Night and OUT by Morning.

Comment: If we cannot see the raw data you use to explain your issue, then it is almost impossible to help find a solution. You refer to Oct 11 but there are no rows in your picture for that date. In addition, using pictures to provide data does not encourage others to attempt to help since it cannot be used as a source of sample data.

Comment: its actually on the 2nd picture IN: 2019-10-11 19:00:00 / OUT: 2019-10-11 07:01:00

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Temp_Table Table
(
    Empoyee_id int,
    [Date] datetime,
    [InOutMode] bit
)

INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
(
    Empoyee_id,[Date],[InOutMode]

)
SELECT 104,'20191011 09:30',1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191011 19:30',0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191012 09:30',1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191012 12:30',0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191012 19:00',0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191013 09:30',1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191013 07:30',0
UNION ALL
SELECT 104,'20191014 09:30',1 

SELECT Empoyee_id,[Date],[In],IIF([In]>[Out],null,[Out]) as [Out]
FROM
(
    SELECT Empoyee_id,CAST([Date] AS DATE) AS [Date],
    MIN(IIF(InOutMode=1,[Date],NULL)) AS [In] ,
    MAX(IIF(InOutMode=0,[Date],NULL)) AS [Out]
    FROM @Temp_Table
    GROUP BY Empoyee_id,CAST([Date] AS DATE)
)A
```

Comment: Nice but only select the Date not typing the Date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;
WITH Ins as (
  Select *
  FROM   HR_DTR_Device 
  WHERE  InOutMode = 0
),
Outs as (
  Select *
  FROM   HR_DTR_Device
  WHERE  InOutMode = 1
)
SELECT Ins.ID,
       Ins.Employee_ID,
       Ins.Date as [In],
       (
         SELECT Min(Outs.Date)
         FROM   Outs
         WHERE  Ins.Employee_ID = Outs.Employee_ID
            AND Outs.Date > Ins.Date
       ) as [Out]
FROM   Ins
WHERE  Ins.Employee_ID = '104'
```

What this does:

1. Separates the `Ins` and the `Outs`, as if they were separate data sources. Using **Common Table Expressions** allows you, in effect, to pre-define subqueries and give them names.
2. For each record in the `Ins`, looks for the smallest date from the `Outs` that is still larger than the `In` date. (This assumes that your records are complete, and that you can't ever have two `Ins` in a row because someone forgot to clock out.)
3. Doesn't make any assumptions about when the `Out` date happens, just that it's later than the `In` date (by definition). That way, you don't have to worry about whether the employee left later the same day or early the next day (if you have employees working different shifts.)
4. Will also show any entries where the employee clocked in but has not yet clocked out.

I think your big error was here:

```
 (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM HR_DTR_Device XX 
 WHERE InOutMode = 1
   AND XX.Employee_ID = AA.Employee_ID
   AND CAST(XX.Date AS DATE) = CAST(AA.Date AS DATE)) AS 'Out'
```

You are returning the largest date for that employee that is on the same calendar date (and is an `Out`). But, if the employee works until the next morning, the date will have changed!

You could fix this by changing your test to this:

```
CAST(DATEADD(d, -1, XX.Date) AS DATE) = CAST(AA.Date AS DATE)
```

... but then it will ONLY work for employees who worked overnight, whereas my solution simply finds the next time the employee clocked out after they clocked in, regardless of whether it's the same day, the next day, or the next week!

If you like this solution, please mark it as your accepted solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Ins.ID, Ins.Employee_ID, Ins.Date could not be bound same sa Outs.Date

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i am using 2014

Comment: You took the whole selection I wrote, and tried it? Starting from the `;`?

Comment: yes but i found a solution and idea regarding on what you had answer thanks :)

Comment: I see the problem with mine -- I left out a comma!  I'll fix that!